# C# host app closes when a PInvoke C / C ++ DLL call exit (-1);

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, exit

I have a C# application that **PInvokes** a compiled DLL in VisualC, which closes the entire process when the **exit(-1)** method is executed; inside the DLL.

I don't have the source code of the native DLL and I understand that the DLL is part of the process and **exit(n);** close the host process.

**I got recommendations like:**

- Modify the native DLL.
- Use an AppDomain (There are too many
  dependencies and the application is too extensive).
- Reimplement the native DLL (It is too extensive).

**The question is:**

- Is it possible to capture **exit(n);** in the C# managed application and prevent the complete application from closing?
- Or using some attribute in the method that invokes the native DLL?

Comment: maybe be kind of useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938099/catch-error-in-exe-file-if-called-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: The C/C++ code winds up calling [the Windows API `ExitProcess()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess), and there's no way to intercept that.

Comment: @JohnB This is not a separate process, it is a DLL load using PInvoke. when a DLL executes exit(n) handlers are closed and release and cleaning is performed, any way to capture SIGCHLD?

Comment: Try :  Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to hook the process exiting. One solution is to patch the DLL binary to remove that call and replace it with a nop or something. That would be my recommendation.

Otherwise, just for fun, here is some sample code that uses a hook on the Windows API to do this. I don't recommend to use it as it can have some side effects (your call). It uses the [MinHook](https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook) binaries for the ground low-level hack/hook work.

Here is some C dll code that call `exit`:

```
extern "C" void _stdcall CallExit()
{
  printf("Let's try an exit...\n");
  exit(1234);
  printf("I survived this!\n");
}
```

And here is the C# caller

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var hook = new MinHook())
        {
            // hook ExitProcess which is the Windows API underneath exit.
            var fake1 = hook.CreateHook<ExitProcess>("kernel32.dll", nameof(ExitProcess), Fake);
            hook.EnableHook(fake1);

            // on recent Windows, we must also hook CorExitProcess
            // because exit (defined in ucrtbased) always try it before calling ExitProcess
            // and if you only hook ExitProcess, the process hangs for some reason
            var fake2 = hook.CreateHook<CorExitProcess>("mscoree.dll", nameof(CorExitProcess), Fake);
            hook.EnableHook(fake2);

            CallExit();
            Console.ReadLine();

            hook.DisableHook(fake1);
            hook.DisableHook(fake2);
        }
    }

    static void Fake(int exitCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hmmm... nope, I want to live forever. Exit code: " + exitCode);
    }

    private delegate void ExitProcess(int uExitCode);
    private delegate void CorExitProcess(int uExitCode);

    [DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
    private static extern void CallExit();
}
```

When ran (tested on Windows 10) it displays this (for some reason, `CorExitProcess` is called twice)

```
Let's try an exit...
Hmmm... nope, I want to live forever. Exit code: 1234
Hmmm... nope, I want to live forever. Exit code: 1234
Hmmm... nope, I want to live forever. Exit code: 1234
I survived this!
```

And here is some C# interop utility code to use MinHook in C#:

```
public sealed class MinHook : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IntPtr> _module = new Lazy<IntPtr>(HookNativeProcs, true);
    public static string NativeDllPath { get; private set; }

    private IntPtr _handle;

    public MinHook()
    {
        var hook = _module.Value;
        CheckError(_MH_Initialize());
    }

    public IntPtr CreateHook<T>(string libraryName, string procName, T detour)
    {
        if (libraryName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(libraryName));

        if (procName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(procName));

        var module = LoadLibrary(libraryName);
        if (module == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        var address = GetProcAddress(module, procName);
        if (address == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        var ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<T>(detour);
        CheckError(_MH_CreateHook(address, ptr, out IntPtr original));
        return address;
    }

    public void EnableHook(IntPtr hook)
    {
        if (hook == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(hook));

        CheckError(_MH_EnableHook(hook));
    }

    public void DisableHook(IntPtr hook)
    {
        if (hook == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(hook));

        CheckError(_MH_DisableHook(hook));
    }

    public void RemoveHook(IntPtr hook)
    {
        if (hook == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(hook));

        CheckError(_MH_RemoveHook(hook));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var handle = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _handle, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CheckError(_MH_Uninitialize());
        }
    }

    private Exception CheckError(MH_STATUS status, bool throwOnError = true)
    {
        if (status == MH_STATUS.MH_OK)
            return null;

        var ex = new Exception(status.ToString());
        if (throwOnError)
            throw ex;

        return ex;
    }

    // with this code, we support AnyCpu targets
    private static IEnumerable<string> PossibleNativePaths
    {
        get
        {
            string bd = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string rsp = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
            string bitness = IntPtr.Size == 8 ? "64" : "86";
            bool searchRsp = rsp != null && bd != rsp;

            // look for an env variable
            string env = GetEnvironmentVariable("MINHOOK_X" + bitness + "_DLL");
            if (env != null)
            {
                // full path?
                if (Path.IsPathRooted(env))
                {
                    yield return env;
                }
                else
                {
                    // relative path?
                    yield return Path.Combine(bd, env);
                    if (searchRsp)
                        yield return Path.Combine(rsp, env);
                }
            }

            // look in appdomain path
            string name = "minhook.x" + bitness + ".dll";
            yield return Path.Combine(bd, name);
            if (searchRsp)
                yield return Path.Combine(rsp, name);

            name = "minhook.dll";
            yield return Path.Combine(bd, name); // last resort, hoping the bitness's right, we do not recommend it
            if (searchRsp)
                yield return Path.Combine(rsp, name);
        }
    }

    private static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            if (value != null)
                return value;

            value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
            if (value != null)
                return value;

            return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
        }
        catch
        {
            // probably an access denied, continue
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr HookNativeProcs()
    {
        var path = PossibleNativePaths.FirstOrDefault(p => File.Exists(p));
        if (path == null)
            throw new Exception("Cannot determine native MinHook dll path. Process is running " + (IntPtr.Size == 8 ? "64" : "32") + "-bit.");

        NativeDllPath = path;
        var module = LoadLibrary(path);
        if (module == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception("Cannot load native MinHook dll from path '" + path + "'. Process is running " + (IntPtr.Size == 8 ? "64" : "32") + "-bit.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

        _MH_Initialize = LoadProc<MH_Initialize>(module);
        _MH_Uninitialize = LoadProc<MH_Uninitialize>(module);
        _MH_CreateHook = LoadProc<MH_CreateHook>(module);
        _MH_RemoveHook = LoadProc<MH_RemoveHook>(module);
        _MH_EnableHook = LoadProc<MH_EnableHook>(module);
        _MH_DisableHook = LoadProc<MH_DisableHook>(module);
        return module;
    }

    private static T LoadProc<T>(IntPtr module, string name = null)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            name = typeof(T).Name;
        }

        var address = GetProcAddress(module, name);
        if (address == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception("Cannot load library function '" + name + "' from '" + NativeDllPath + "'. Please make sure MinHook is the latest one.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

        return (T)(object)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(address, typeof(T));
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate MH_STATUS MH_Initialize();
    private static MH_Initialize _MH_Initialize;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate MH_STATUS MH_Uninitialize();
    private static MH_Uninitialize _MH_Uninitialize;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate MH_STATUS MH_CreateHook(IntPtr pTarget, IntPtr pDetour, out IntPtr ppOriginal);
    private static MH_CreateHook _MH_CreateHook;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate MH_STATUS MH_RemoveHook(IntPtr pTarget);
    private static MH_RemoveHook _MH_RemoveHook;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate MH_STATUS MH_EnableHook(IntPtr pTarget);
    private static MH_EnableHook _MH_EnableHook;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate MH_STATUS MH_DisableHook(IntPtr pTarget);
    private static MH_DisableHook _MH_DisableHook;
}

public enum MH_STATUS
{
    // Unknown error. Should not be returned.
    MH_UNKNOWN = -1,

    // Successful.
    MH_OK = 0,

    // MinHook is already initialized.
    MH_ERROR_ALREADY_INITIALIZED,

    // MinHook is not initialized yet, or already uninitialized.
    MH_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED,

    // The hook for the specified target function is already created.
    MH_ERROR_ALREADY_CREATED,

    // The hook for the specified target function is not created yet.
    MH_ERROR_NOT_CREATED,

    // The hook for the specified target function is already enabled.
    MH_ERROR_ENABLED,

    // The hook for the specified target function is not enabled yet, or already
    // disabled.
    MH_ERROR_DISABLED,

    // The specified pointer is invalid. It points the address of non-allocated
    // and/or non-executable region.
    MH_ERROR_NOT_EXECUTABLE,

    // The specified target function cannot be hooked.
    MH_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION,

    // Failed to allocate memory.
    MH_ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOC,

    // Failed to change the memory protection.
    MH_ERROR_MEMORY_PROTECT,

    // The specified module is not loaded.
    MH_ERROR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND,

    // The specified function is not found.
    MH_ERROR_FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND
}
```