# How to catch runtime exception of another process in c#?

Tags: c#, process, exception, try-catch, runtimeexception

Writing a piece of code which opens another process.

```
public void StartProcess()
{
    Process p = Process.Start("Process1");
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
}
```

This will start process 1. Is there a way to catch runtime exceptions in Process1?

It is a different question from the code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279181/catch-another-process-unhandled-exception) as it tells you how to catch a runtime exception to a .net exectuable assembly. The application I'm opening is built using Delphi and I do not have the source code

Comment: @giladgreen It is not a duplicate as the code you showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279181/catch-another-process-unhandled-exception) tells you how to catch a runtime exception to a .net exectuable assembly. The application I'm opening is built using Delphi and I do not have the source code

Answer (score 1):

Process must catch the exception itself. You may then deliver error reports through an observer pattern.

Comment: Process1 is a third party application. This just starts the process. I dont understand what you mean by **process must catch the exception itself**.

Comment: I mean you can read the result and track the stdout of another application, but you can not really handle exceptions. The application has to cooperate with you on this. Otherwise you will get the result, but never really know what's happening inside.

Comment: problem is i do not have the source code of application. is there a way to catch any exception that occurs in any application

Comment: If the exception is not handled by the application, you may see it from stdout, but can do nothing about it. **The unhandled exception will terminate the thread** of the application in which it appeared.

Comment: how do i know if the thread is terminated ?

Comment: You do not know that, but you can assume that from the application's output. Simply said: the application is a blackbox, you can do nothing about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121334/discussion-between-alex-t-and-boris-shchegolev).